# Express.js : How to chain multiple templates in single html page?

Tags: express, mean-stack

Given 4 .html templates files `header.html`, `body_l.html`, `body_r.html`, `footer.html` for :

`+-------------------------------+
|          Header               |
+----------------------+--------+
|                      |        |
|                      |        |
|   Body_left          | Body_r |
|                      |        |
|                      |        |
+----------------------+--------+
|          Footer               |
+-------------------------------+`

**How to use 4 html templates to send back a single html page ?**

---

**I tried** variations of :

```
//assuming app is express Object.
app.get('/',function(req,res){

     res.render('header.html', { data1 : "username"       ;} )
        .render('body_l.html', { data2 : "page content"   ;} )
        .render('body_r.html', { data3 : "sidebar content";} )
        .render('footer.html', { data4 : "website footer" ;} )
    res.end();
});
```

Without success.

**Note:** A true begginer with MEAN stack, if this questions is poorly worded, please guide me with simple keywords and I will do my homework.

Answer (score 2):

What template engine are you using with Express? Jade, Handlebars, EJS? I believe they all support "partials" or "includes", but differently. Some relevant documentation:

EJS includes - https://github.com/tj/ejs#includes

Handlebars partials - http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html

Jade includes - http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/

Essentially, you would render the outermost view or template file from your route's function to provide the layout, and it would include the inner content blocks of sub-templates or partials where appropriate.

For example, assuming EJS, pseudocode for `layout.ejs` which you would render might look something like:

```
 <body>
    <div id="header">
         <% include partial/header.ejs %>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyLeft">
        <% include partial/bodyLeft.ejs %>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyRight">
        <% include partial/bodyRight.ejs %>
    </div>  
    <div id="footer">
        <% include partial/footer.ejs %>
    </div>
 </body>
```

You then call it via :

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('layout.ejs', { data : { allDataHere } ;} )
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Ejs, Mustachejs, Handlebarsjs. Ok, this may be what I look for : `partiales` | `includes`. Thanks :) (digging in)

Comment: @mmcaff - Don't think you need to call `res.end()` after `res.render`.